# Expectation value of the anticommutator of the bosonic creation and annihilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

The number operator  is given by:

$$\hat{n}= a^{\dagger}  a.$$

For a presentation, I have to derive the expectation value of the anticommutator of the **bosonic** operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ :

$$\langle \{a , a^{\dagger} \} \rangle  = \langle 2 \, \hat{n} + 1 \rangle $$

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to specify the stae in which you are taking the expectation value.

Comment: If the state is $\sum\rho_{mn}|m\rangle\langle n|$, the expectation is $\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\sum_k(2k+1)|k\rangle\langle k|)=\sum_k(2k+1)\rho_{kk}$.

Comment: $\rho_{kk}$ should than be the probability of each state or? This would give $\rho_{kk}=\frac{\exp(- \beta \, k \, E)}{Z}=   \frac{\exp(- \beta \, k \, E)}{\exp(-\sum_k \beta \, k \, E)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[a,a^\dagger]=1$ gives $aa^\dagger=1+a^\dagger a$

So $\{a,a^\dagger\}=aa^\dagger+a^\dagger a=2a^\dagger a+1=2\hat{n}+1$

To calculate the expectation value $\langle 2\hat{n}+1 \rangle$ we have (take $\hbar=1$ )

\begin{align}
\langle 2\hat{n}+1 \rangle&=\text{Tr}[\hat{\rho} (2\hat{n}+1)] \\
&=\text{Tr}[\frac{e^{-\beta \omega (\hat{n}+1/2)}}{\text{Tr}[e^{-\beta \omega (\hat{n}+1/2)}]} (2\hat{n}+1)] \\
\end{align}
First let's compute $Z=\text{Tr}[e^{-\beta \omega (\hat{n}+1/2)}]=e^{-\beta \omega/2}\sum_{n}\langle n|e^{-\beta \omega \hat{n}}|n \rangle=e^{-\beta \omega/2}\sum_{n}e^{-\beta \omega n} $

Then
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}[\frac{e^{-\beta \omega (\hat{n}+1/2)}}{Z} (2\hat{n}+1)]&=1+2\frac{e^{-\beta \omega/2} \sum_{n}n e^{-n \beta \omega}}{Z} \\
&=1+2\frac{ \sum_{n}n e^{-n \beta \omega}}{\sum_{n}e^{-\beta \omega n}} \\
\langle 2\hat{n}+1 \rangle&=1+\frac{2}{e^{\beta \omega}-1}
\end{align}

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Sorry if my question was a bit misleading. I wanted to know how derive the expectation value of $\langle 2 \hat{n} + 1 \rangle$

Comment: what is the state you are considering?

Comment: All possible states I guess. Where the probability of each state is given by $p_n = \frac{\exp \left(- \beta \, n \, E_n \right)} {Z} $ with $Z$ being the partition function. According to my professor, this should yield the fluctuation-dissipation theorem.

Comment: Maybe you can calculate that by density operator. i.e. expectation value of an observable A$<A>=Tr[\rho A]$ where $\rho=\frac{e^{-\beta H}}{Tr[e^{-\beta H}]} $

Comment: I have updated my answer and see if that will help you, though I don't see the relation to fluctuation-dissipation thm.

Comment: Thank you thats awesome. You can see the fluctuation-dissipation theorem when you rewrite this to: $\langle 2 \hat{n} + 1 \rangle = \coth(\frac{\beta \, \omega}{2})$